# What name put in attribute for of label

Tags: html

I have the following markup:

```
<label>Date of birth:</label>
<select id="day">
  <option>Day</option>
</select>
<select id="month">
  <option>Month</option>
</select>
<select year="year">
  <option>Year</option>
</select>
```

And I don't know exactly what to put in the for attribute of label.

Comment: the `for` attribute is used to reference the element the `label` is for by `id`. For example, `<label for="day">Date of Birth:</label>`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, because the `for=""` attribute can only be used to specify a single `<input />`/`<select>`/`<textarea>`. The `for=""` attribute **is entirely optional** - so don't feel compelled to always define it.

Another option is to use an `<input type="date" />` input instead of separate `<select>` inputs - this also makes it easy to prevent invalid input like `2017-02-31` unless you have a client-script that hides invalid `day` options:

```
<label>Date of birth:</label>
<input type="date" name="dob" />
```

If you really want to use the `for=""` attribute with separate `<select>` inputs, you could set it to the first `<select>` (in your case: the `day` input), which at least is consistent about it switching the user's focus to the right input (or close enough):

```
<label for="day" />
<select id="day">
    ...
</select>
```